# Second string corrupt after multiple realloc calls

Tags: c++, realloc

I was writing a function that allow someone to expand an array of char*, and while doing some test I noticed that when I put more than 3 elements, the second one become something corrupted.

This is the function itself:

```
    void Data::PushBack_String(char** PtrToPtr, char* Ptr, unsigned short Index)
    {
         unsigned short String_Length;
         for(String_Length = 0; Ptr[String_Length] != '\0'; ++String_Length);
                                                            ++String_Length;

         char* NewPtr = (char*)malloc(String_Length);
         strcpy(NewPtr, Ptr);   

         PtrToPtr = (char**)realloc(PtrToPtr, Index);
         PtrToPtr[Index] = NewPtr;
    }
```

Also noticed that when the number of elements exceed 17 elements the program crashes.

Comment: I can think of no reason outside of academic coursework why you're not using a `std::unordered_map<unsigned short, std::string>` for this task.

Comment: I know there are easiest way to so this, but I want to learn how to manipulate dynamic arrays.

Comment: The way you calculate `String_Length` is wrong. You increment `String_Length` twice in each loop. It goes pass the end of the string if the length is odd.

Comment: @DerekLedbetter note the semi-colon after the for-loop closing parenthesis. the additional increment is outside and is the OP's way of accounting for the null-char.

Answer (score 0):

The proper use of `malloc` is like `malloc(String_Length * sizeof(char)+1)`. You should add 1 to account for the ending `'\0'` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `strdup()` instead. It'll cover **the one byte for NULL termination you have forgotten**. And it's much more readable.